# How should one align an image in the same line with the content of a <nav> tag?

Tags: html, css, nav

[This image will make it easy to understand my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gb602.png) 
Is there any way to make the logo image perfectly in the same line with the other content of the nav tag ?

This is my  code;

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><img id="nav_img" src="nav_img.png" alt="logo" title="nav_img"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#"> About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'> FAQ </a></li>
    <li><a href='#'> Download </a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox to vertically align your logo with the rest of your list items by just turning the parent element of the elements you want to vertically center, which in your case, is the `<ul>` to a flexbox (`display:flex;`) and specifying the vertical and horizontal alignment of it's child elements to be centered (`align-items: center;` & `justify-content:center;`).

This will automatically change your child `<li>` elements to flex items and vertically+horizontally align them to each other.

---

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of what I have described above:

```css
ul {display:flex; align-items: center;justify-content:center;list-style: none;}
```

```html
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><img id="nav_img" src="https://picsum.photos/75/75" alt="logo" title="nav_img"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#"> About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'> FAQ </a></li>
    <li><a href='#'> Download </a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yes it works thanks but the content is not centered. I tried align-content but no result too.. any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "justify-content: center;" to your ul after align-items.

```
ul {
display:flex; 
align-items: center;
justify-content; center;
list-style: none;
}
```

Edit: Having align-items and justify-content both being set to center with display flex will make all of the children centered across both axes.